# DVB-S streaming from source to media server

Tags: vlc, http-live-streaming, transcoding, dvb, fmle

i am streaming some FTA channels from 
http://www.tbsdtv.com/products/tbs6985-dvb-s2-quad-tuner-pcie-card.html

using mediaportal
http://www.team-mediaportal.com/

and then i get rtsp url from mediaportal of channel i timeshift

and vlc i can send that stream to mediaserver FMS to get HLS, HDS, RTMP, RTSP

i have 3 servers running erlyvideo (flussonic)
so it take care of the delivery.

i want some alternate solution beside that
i have done some methods to work this our

including
VLC
IPTVL
Dvbdream

but the quality is better when i stream some thing as file, only FMLE works good with live stream, but for that we only can use directshow enabled devices like

http://www.viewcast.com/products/osprey-cards

i am doing it on windows.

if some one have any more methods or want to share his version please do so

Comment: can i get live feed from mediaportal,

Comment: mediaportal first dump stream to ts file and stream it from there